# Google Chrome browser issue : reset/clear cache

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, caching

I've already researched this issue extensively on google, and such.

Here it is :  the google chrome browser does not automatically load new web-pages;  instead, it loads old ones.

I did not much bother with this.......until I started coding.

The funny thing is :  I didn't even realize that the chrome-browser was the culprit behind most of the situations when my PHP/HTML code did not work !  I would spend HOURS writing and re-writing code; when I tested it, it would give me the same "old" output.

It was purely by accident that, one fine day, I decided to completely clear out my chrome cache (clear my broswer data).............and, when I tested some "old" code, it gave me a "new" result !!!!

Imagine my amazement.

From that day onwards, I developed the very irritating, annoying, but necessary, habit of clearing out my browser-cache **EACH TIME** I made changes to my code.

My code is currently progressing rapidly, and I am becoming more irritated with having to refresh my cache each time I want to test new code. Hence, I've made the decision to quit google-chrome, and switch to Mozilla.

Upon doing some research, though, the only reference to this problem was found here :

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xR-6YAkcASQ

The solution put forward is the one I employed from the start, after I first noticed this problem.

Apparently, there seems to be no other solution.

So, why am I writing this post, then??   Well, it's quite simple :  the reason I am posting here is in the hope that........maybe.......someone knows of another way around this --- perhaps, something that can be injected into one's code (or, perhaps, within the past year, or month, or week, or even within the past 24 hours, Google has somehow had a much-needed "brainwave", and finally fixed this problem !!)

Comment: I also faced a issue like this , where even i spent hours in finding error in the  code, where chrome was the culprit. :p Hence whenever im trying a piece of code, i make sure i try it in other browsers as well (firefox , opera) That actually helps.

Comment: yep, same here. Just spent a hole day debugging a .CSS / .PHP and it turned out the issue was as simple as clearing cache’s - oh well, this is how we learn!

Answer (score 2):

I know two methods that may help you

1. Set the next HTTP headers in php

   ```
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
   header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   ```
2. In Chrome, right click on this page and Inspect Element => There is a Settings icon in top right of Inspector. Click there, then select Disable cache checkbox. This will clear your cache everytime you refresh the page and have the Inspector opened.

Hope one of this two ways helps you. Please take in mind that any code executed on server side will change the returned page no matter the cache. The cache only affects downloaded files like images and scripts.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Comment: Thanks, besciualex.  Just one question :  if I tick that checkbox "Disable Cache"...........will this work ALWAYS?  I mean :  will it disable cache for google chrome in general?  Or, is this a temporary solution for the particular page which I am browsing at any given time?   (I checked the Chrome Settings itself, and I did not find that checkbox.  It appears only here, under "Inspect Element")

Comment: @newuserphp Unfortunately it will disable cache only when Inspect Element is opened. P.S. Ctrl + F5 is a clear-refresh, which means every refresh done this way will fully reload all cached elements. However I encountered situation when this didn't work. (I can say it worked about 95% of time)

Comment: Hmmm............so, the only solution that works 100% is indeed the one in the google post :  one needs to manually CLEAR CACHE.   It's amazing that Google has no clue about this issue.   Thanks, anyway  :=)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned is most likely to happen with css or javascript files. What you can do is, when you link that file in html page, you can append some query string to file link url, with query string value being `md5` of the file.

For example, if you linking some css file in html, you can do it as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css?v=1<?php echo md5_file("css/styles.css"); ?>" />
```

So each time you make change to "styles.css" file, it the md5 value will be changed and it will always look for updated file rather than cached file as the link will not match.

Comment: Actually, this happens with ALL my files, especially HTML and PHP.  I am not even using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (for me)
I just had this issue and tried adding the meta tags and header info to my php page but it still wasnt working after clearing my cache.

I talked to the web admin and found that he recently updated the caching tags for the domain in htaccess. I asked him to see if he could make it so the Apache server didnt cache on this subdomain. He let me know that he added a line in htaccess to ignore Expired Tags which worked after I cleared my browser cache again. Now it works correctly updating my web page without pulling the cached data.

Hope this helps someone.